# Prevent "Fit to Window" setting

Tags: javascript

I have the following image and when I click on  it. it will pop out into a **colorbox** modal, but it currently re-sizes it to fit to the window. How would I just resize it up to only the width of the window and have the user scroll down to see the rest of the image?

I'm using the colorbox module. I know I have to unset the innerHeight to auto or something. But how would you override a javascript snippet without affecting other pages on the site?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below Jquery snippet.

```
(function ($) {
var cboxOptions = {
     width: '95%',
     height: '95%',
     maxWidth: '768px',
     maxHeight: '768px',
}

$('#colorbox').colorbox(cboxOptions);

$(window).resize(function(){
   $.colorbox.resize({
     width: window.innerWidth > parseInt(cboxOptions.maxWidth) ? cboxOptions.maxWidth : cboxOptions.width,
         height: window.innerHeight > parseInt(cboxOptions.maxHeight) ? cboxOptions.maxHeight : cboxOptions.height
   });
});
```

Comment: that worked great! how did you figure this out aside from reading the api docs for colorbox.